# In Tiny Epic Galaxies - when do you get your new ships?

Tags: tiny-epic-galaxies

In Tiny Epic Galaxies you can follow people's moves on their turn, and one move might be to upgrade your empire, upon which you'd gain a new ship.

Or similarly you might upgrade at the start of your turn and gain a new ship.

The question is - when do these ships arrive for the purposes of:

- Being able to move them
- Counting them toward receiving energy/culture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ships come in play as soon as you take/follow the "upgrade your empire" action.

In [the rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/121333/official-rule-book-tiny-epic-galaxies)

on page 8:

> If you gain a ship, immediately place it on the center of your Galaxy Mat. This ship can be used on the same turn.